# PHP MySQL: Data insertion issue?

Tags: php, mysql

The following is what i tried to insert data into mysql database. So that I need help in this:

```
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$name = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pwd2'];
//Register Students
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,usermail, username, userpasswd)
    values('$firstname', '$lastname', '$name', '$password')");
```

Comment: where is your database connection?

Comment: And please Sanitize your data before inserting it to your db

Comment: You are using an obselete database API i.e. the `mysql_*` functions which is deprecated. Switch to `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Comment: You don't explain what the problem is. You say you've tried that code, but what is wrong with it? What do you expect and why didn't it work? That's the sort of information we would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE **PDO** or **MYSQLi** than **MYSQL_***

You are having 5 columns 4 columns

Change it to:

```
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pwd2'];
$name=$_POST['name']
//Register Students
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,usermail, username, userpasswd)
values('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$name', '$password')");
if($sql)
{
echo"Inserted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `mysql_affected_rows()`, you can check the inserted row count.

Just do `echo mysql_affected_rows();`;. You can see the number of rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 columns and 4 values,they have to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this :

```
   if(! $sql )
    {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

If not inserted then you will get error and that will tell you what you are missing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your string and your variables

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,usermail, username, userpasswd)values('" .$firstname . "', '" .$lastname ."', '" .$name ."', '" .$password ."')");
```